# Passing props/state between two functional child components in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-props, react-state

I have been looking on google a lot about how to pass props between functional components but very little information seems to be out there(either that or I don't know what keywords to input into google).

I do not need redux or data stored globally, I simply want to pass a JSON object stored in a hook from one component file to another.

I have three files one is the parent and the other two are children, I want to pass the data between the children files.

**Paerent**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ShoppingPageOne from "./ShoppingPageOne";
import ShoppingPageTwo from "./ShoppingPageSecond";

function ShoppingPageContainer() {

  const [pageone_Open, setPageone_Open] = useState(true);
  const [pagetwo_Open, setPagetwo_Open] = useState(false);


  const page_showHandler = () => {
    setPageone_Open(!pageone_Open);
    setPagetwo_Open(!pagetwo_Open);
  };

  return (
    <div className="Shopping_Container">
      <div className="Shopping_Box">
        <h2>Online food shop</h2>
        <div className="Shopping_Page_Container">
          <ShoppingPageOne showOne={pageone_Open} next_ClickHandler={page_showHandler} />
          <ShoppingPageTwo showTwo={pagetwo_Open} Reset_Data={page_showHandler} />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default ShoppingPageContainer;
```

**Child one:**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Data from '../shoppingData/Ingredients';

const ShoppingPageOne = (props) => {

  //element displays
  const [pageone_show, setPageone_show] = useState("pageOne");

  //stores quantities of items as JSON objects
  const [Quantities, setQuantities] = useState({});
  const [QuantiesProps, setQuantitiesProps] = useState(null)


  useEffect(() => {
    //sets info text using Json
    if (props.showOne) {
      setPageone_show("pageOne");
    } else {
      setPageone_show("pageOne hide");
    }
  }, [props.showOne]);


  return (
    <div className={"Shopping_Content " + pageone_show}>
      {Data.map((Ingredients) => {

        //updates Quanties Hook
        const handleChange = (event) => {

          setQuantities({
            ...Quantities,
            [Ingredients.Name]: {
              ...(Quantities[Ingredients.Name] ?? {}),
              quantities: event.target.value
            }
          });
        };

        return (<div className="Shopping_input" key={Ingredients.Name}>
          <p>{Ingredients.Name} £{Ingredients.Price}</p>
          <input onChange={handleChange.bind(this)} min="0" type="number"></input>
        </div>)
      })}
      <div className="Shopping_Buttons">
        <p onClick={props.next_ClickHandler}>Buy Now!</p>
      </div>

    </div>
  );
};

export default ShoppingPageOne;
```

**Child Two**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Data from '../shoppingData/Ingredients';

const ShoppingPageSecond = (props) => {
  //element displays
  const [pagetwo_show, setPagetwo_show] = useState("pageTwo hide");

  useEffect(() => {
    //resets info text
    if (props.showTwo) {
      setPagetwo_show("pageTwo");
    } else {
      setPagetwo_show("pageTwo hide");
    }


  }, [props.showTwo]);




  return (
    <div className={"Shopping_Content " + pagetwo_show}>

      <div className="Shopping_Buttons">
        <p onClick={props.Reset_Data}>Shop Again</p>
      </div>

    </div>
  );
};

export default ShoppingPageSecond;import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Data from '../shoppingData/Ingredients';

const ShoppingPageSecond = (props) => {
  //element displays
  const [pagetwo_show, setPagetwo_show] = useState("pageTwo hide");

  useEffect(() => {
    //resets info text
    if (props.showTwo) {
      setPagetwo_show("pageTwo");
    } else {
      setPagetwo_show("pageTwo hide");
    }


  }, [props.showTwo]);




  return (
    <div className={"Shopping_Content " + pagetwo_show}>

      <div className="Shopping_Buttons">
        <p onClick={props.Reset_Data}>Shop Again</p>
      </div>

    </div>
  );
};

export default ShoppingPageSecond;
```

I simply want to pass the state contained in **Quantities** hook from **Child One** to **Child Two** when "Buy Now!" button is clicked.
What is the best approach to do doing this?

Comment: There are two ways: have the state in a common ancestor and pass it down through the tree manually, or use the [context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext) to do it for you. The example in the docs is for a theme setting. I frequently use it for things needed at multiple levels like theme or details for the logged-in user. With a tree that shallow though I'd probably just do it by hand.

Comment: Thanks, Jared I'll read up about the context API sounds very useful! That being said which method would you recommend out the two?

Comment: For two components that are siblings I'd store the state in the parent. If the nodes are not siblings, or if I think I may need the data at multiple levels of the render tree, I'll stick it in a Context. For instance, rather than have a pageOpen state for each page I'd maybe just keep a currentPage state in a context and make it more widely available perhaps?

Comment: I've implemented context API very simple to use thank you very much

Comment: No problem, glad you got it figured out.

Answer (score 0):

From my understand, I don't pass props between two children under the same parent. Instead, the parent holds the data, and pass the data and mutation function to children as props.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const PageOne = ({ value, setValue }) => {
   const PageOneFunction = () => {
      setValue({
         pageOneData: value.pageOneData + 1,
         pageTwoData: value.pageTwoData + 1,
      });
   };

   return (
      <div>
         <h4>Page One</h4>
         <div>{value.pageOneData}</div>
         <button onClick={PageOneFunction}>
            Increase page one and page two value
         </button>
      </div>
   );
};

const PageTwo = ({ value, setValue }) => {
   const pageTwoFunction = () => {
      setValue({
         pageOneData: 0,
         pageTwoData: 0,
      });
   };

   return (
      <div>
         <h4>Page Two</h4>
         <div>{value.pageTwoData}</div>
         <button onClick={pageTwoFunction}>Reset</button>
      </div>
   );
};

const PageContainer = () => {
   const [data, setData] = useState({
      pageOneData: 0,
      pageTwoData: 0,
   });

   return (
      <div className="bg-white">
         <PageOne value={data} setValue={setData} />
         <PageTwo value={data} setValue={setData} />
      </div>
   );
};

export default PageContainer;
```

Comment: This would qualify as an answer if you included an example in working code.

Comment: In my code example, how would that work say I move the Quantities hook to the parent? how would I update the hook using the input fields on Child one and pass them into Child two? any links with examples you can provide?